# how to retrieve the first hashtag of a tweet in Python?

Tags: python, twitter

As title, what's the code for retrieving the first hashtag of a tweet in Python?

Tag output as a string 
`tag= for tag in tw.split() if tag.startswith("#")}`

Comment: `[tag for tag in tw.split() if tag.startswith("#")][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex ...

Something like

```
>>> tweet = 'some text #tagtag #anothertag'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\B\#\w+\b', tweet)
['#tagtag', '#anothertag']
```

Use https://www.regex101.com to help you tweak the regex